# Replace text in docx file with content of another docx file

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml

I'm trying to use OpenXml to replace a text "**Veteran**" in file A.docx with content in B.docx . If B.docx contains text or paragraph , it works fine and I get modified A.docx file. 
However, if B.docx contains a table, then the code doesn't work.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SearchAndReplace(@"C:\A.docx", @"C:\B.docx");
        }

        public static void SearchAndReplace(string docTo, string docFrom)
        {
            List<WordprocessingDocument> docList = new List<WordprocessingDocument>();
            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(docTo, true))
            using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc1 = WordprocessingDocument.Open(docFrom, true))
            {
                var parts = wordDoc1.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants().FirstOrDefault();
                docList.Add(wordDoc);
                docList.Add(wordDoc1);

                if (parts != null)
                {
                    foreach (var node in parts.ChildElements)
                    {
                        if (node is Table)
                        {
                            ParseTable(docList, (Table)node, textBuilder);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static void ParseText(List<WordprocessingDocument> wpd, Paragraph node, StringBuilder textBuilder)
        {
            Body body = wpd[0].MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
            Body body1 = wpd[1].MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

            string content = body1.InnerXml;
            var paras = body.Elements<Paragraph>();

            foreach (var para in paras)
            {
                foreach (var run in para.Elements<Run>())
                {
                    foreach (var text in run.Elements<Text>())
                    {
                        if (text.Text.Contains("Veteran"))
                        {
                            run.InnerXml.Replace(run.InnerXml, content);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static void ParseTable(List<WordprocessingDocument> wpd, Table node, StringBuilder textBuilder)
        {
            foreach (var row in node.Descendants<TableRow>())
            {
                textBuilder.Append("| ");
                foreach (var cell in row.Descendants<TableCell>())
                {
                    foreach (var para in cell.Descendants<Paragraph>())
                    {
                        ParseText(wpd, para, textBuilder);
                    }
                    textBuilder.Append(" | ");
                }
                textBuilder.AppendLine("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to make this work ? Is there a better way to replace content with another docx file?

Comment: You don't provide enough information about what's being brought into the target document. And the code in the question is out-of-context: we have no idea what the parameters being passed into the procedures are. If you want to insert an entire document research the concept `altChunk`.

Comment: Content that needs to be copied into A.docx could be text or paragraph or table or image or any content that is in B.docx file. 
Edited the code in question to clarify the way "SearchAndReplace" method is being called.

Comment: Did you research the other questions related to search and replace? Secondly, did you study the basics of Open XML markup? You can't just insert any markup (e.g., table markup) anywhere in the document. A `w:tbl` (`Table`) is a block-level element that can't be added to a `w:p` (`Paragraph`), for example.

Comment: Yes, I do understand that xml schema is different for a table or a paragraph in docx file so would be difficult to insert it as is and I am getting invalid docx file which does not even open . After researching I am able to get text or paragraph working but not if docx contains a table.
Hence, my question is there any possible solution to handle such content ?
One way, I believe might be that validate each and every xml tags of target file and recreate the whole set again in the new file. I just need guidance towards any existing library or framework to handle such scenarios!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not having enough detail for a specific answer, here's how you solve such problems in general:

1. Ensure you understand the Open XML specification and valid Open XML markup on an appropriate level of detail.

   - If you don't understand what `w:document`, `w:body`, `w:p`, `w:r`, `w:t`, `w:tbl`, etc. are and how they relate to each other, you have no chance.
   - You must look at actual Open XML markup, e.g., using the [Open XML Productivity Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) or the [Open XML Package Editor for Modern Visual Studios](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bsivanov.OpenXMLPackageEditorforVisualStudio) to get to an appropriate level of understanding and develop Open XML-based solutions.
2. Understand that most Open XML-related code **transforms** some source markup into some target markup. Therefore, you must:

   - understand the source and target markup first and then
   - define the transformation required to create the target from the source.

Depending on what you need to do, the Open XML Productivity Tool can help create the transforming code. If you have a source and target document, you can use the Productivity Tool to compare those documents. This shows the difference in the markup, so you see what markup is created, deleted, or changed. It even shows you the Open XML SDK-based code required to effect the change.

In my own use cases, I typically prefer to write [recursive, pure functional transformations](http://www.ericwhite.com/blog/recursive-pure-functional-transforms-series/). While you need to wrap your head around the concept, this is an extremely powerful approach.

In your case, you should:

- take a few representative, manually-created samples of source (A.docx with "Vetaran" still to be replaced) and target (A.docx with "Veteran" replaced as desired) documents;
- look at the Open XML markup of the source and target documents; and
- write code that creates the target markup.

Once you have created code that at least tries to create valid target Open XML markup, you could come back with further questions in case you identify further issues.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. That is really insightful, and provided me with more things to look into!!